# Why does exec file generate 4 processes in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, embedded, cygwin, cross-compilation

I build my RTAI-model-source（generated by simulink） in CygWin with gcc-linux-4.1 (cross-compiler of CygWin) on Windows, and generate ELF successfully. and the ELF runs correctly on Ubuntu.

After the ELF is running correctly on Ubuntu, there are four processes with the same name but different process-id in the system monitor.

But if I build my source with `gcc` on Linux, it generates only 1 process, so I think `fork()` or `exec()` may not be called.

How can one exec file make four processes?

The `ps -elF` shows:

```
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root      3679  3314  0  57   - -  4362 hrtime 17:44 pts/1    00:00:00 /root/Test/test
5 S root      3680  3679  0  57   - -  4362 poll_s 17:44 pts/1    00:00:00 /root/Test/test
5 S root      3681  3680  0  56   - -  4362 rt_sch 17:44 pts/1    00:00:00 /root/Test/test
5 S root      3682  3680  0 -40   - -  4362 rt_sch 17:44 pts/1    00:00:00 /root/Test/test
```

Comment: It's possible that GCC compiling for Windows does multi-threading where compiling for native linux execution does fork/exec. Or maybe I misunderstand where the two executables run.

Comment: The two executables run on Ubuntu, the cross-compiled one generate 4 processes and the native generate 1 process.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly normal for certain processes to create other copies of themselves after execution, usually to improve performance through parallel execution. As for how it works, the process fork(2)'s (it may or may not also exec(2) another copy of itself, depending on the way it is implemented). See `man 2 fork` and `man 2 exec`.

Essentially, new processes in Linux are first created as copies of the program calling them using fork(2). After that, they may replace their process image by using exec(2). This is the usual workflow when using, for example, a shell to execute commands. If it is the same process, there may be no subsequent exec -- it's also possible to have code executed that is conditional upon being in a certain child without having to exec.

Cambridge University has [a good page on how this works](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/unix/fork.html) if you want more information.

Comment: thanks, i know the fork() and exec(), but i build my source on linux, and it generate only 1 process, so i think fork() or exec() may not be called.